# Best Standard Class to store Object List in?

Tags: c++, list, boost, std

What are classes that represent unindexed list with features including checking if an object is in the list?

```
list<char> list;
list.add("obj");
if(list.inlist("obj")) doStuff();
list.remove("obj");
```

Preferably the class would have to be in the standard or boost library, but if you know any other means answer anyways because it might be interesting regardless.

I am aware there is a `std::list` class but it doesn't have the functionality I am looking for. (Checking if an object is in the list)

Comment: you can check an object in the list using `find`

Comment: Depends on lots of requirements you might have on class. Do you need to find an object often? Do you need to preserve the order? Etc...

Comment: @Erbureth the only features that'll be used are the features in the example really. Any fancy stuff will just be ignored. Especially the `inlist` feature will be used a lot.

Comment: in that case `std::set` is your answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a use case for [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set). This keeps track of duplicates, without the overhead of keeping them ordered.

Answer (score 5):

If you need only to lookup objects, you can use [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) or [`std::multiset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset)

If C++11 is an option, you can use their [unordered](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) [counterparts](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multiset)

Comment: That's a very good point. Maybe these data structs are more appropriate.

Comment: Consider using `std::unordered_set` if the objects are hashable and order is insignificant.

Comment: @not-rightfold That is a good option too, if C++11 is allowed and no set intersections/unions are needed (as seems to be the case)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [std::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) to look for an object inside a container.

Comment: In that case what'd be the best container to use? I'd guess a standard list. (As it doesn't waste resources on indices. )

Comment: A vector does not store indices.